# Epistemic Parity

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-religion

I am trying to work out if I understand the term *epistemic parity*. This is in the context of pluralism exclusivism ect. The resource I am working from states

> A religious exclusivist would deny the earlier claim that parties are under an epistemic obligation to reassess their claims, and also deny epistemic parity to the other.

Would a pluralist say there is epistemic parity between two faiths?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you spell out what you mean by ‘epistemic parity’ and ‘equal evidence’? An example might help. Also, say you’re right: two believers in different world faiths are on epistemic parity if and only if they have the equal evidence. How would it follow that all religions are on epistemic parity? Religions themselves don’t ‘have’ evidence in the way that agents do; so, the notion of epistemic parity might not even be applicable. If it is, the definition leaves open that some religions *don’t* have ‘equal evidence’ as others.

Comment: @MarkOxford I am trying to use the question to get what epistemic parity is in the context of religious pluralism.

Comment: @MarkOxford I have clarified the question (I hope)

Comment: +1 Perhaps not between any two faiths, but I can see the pluralist recognizing that the evidence underdetermines the selection of one faith over some others as a better choice.  It would be similar to picking a position in the stock market or accepting beliefs in competing quantum physics interpretations.  They may not be all equally valid, but some might be.  Ultimately a choice has to be made .  One could also claim there is epistemic parity between two specific faiths and nonetheless one chooses one over the other.

Comment: I’m still not entirely sure how ‘epistemic parity’ is being used here; but (depending on what counts as religious evidence) I don’t think a pluralist will *automatically* grant epistemic parity to all religions. Say one religion is based on deep, clear, convincing, valid arguments (for the existence of God), while the other is based on a lunatic’s fever dreams. Then if there’s any substance to our notion of epistemic parity, we’d probably want to say that these two are not epistemically on par – even if we are pluralists. (Btw., do you have a particular version of pluralism in mind?)

Comment: @MarkOxford I think you are correct. Hick argues that Satanism should not be considered on the same level as Christianity. I am working towards responding to the claim that _in a multicultural society, the diversity of religious traditions and moral views makes illegitimate any claim to objective truth with regards to religious beliefs._ Which is an unfair A-level question. The extract is from the markscheme which is looking for a discussion of the epistemological implications of pluralism.

Comment: I see. So, your take on this is: Can a pluralist hold that there’s objective truth regarding religious beliefs? As you say, Hick (and my example) point out one way to hold this: that there’s no epistemically ‘best’ religion, doesn’t imply that all religions are on par. Another way to get to objective truth might be to look for views / arguments that the ‘better’ religions share. Also, can’t a pluralist still be strict about what counts as (religious) evidence? Spelling out ‘pluralism’ and ‘epistemically on par’ might uncover some interesting corners in logical space.

Comment: @MarkOxford Thanks for your support, it is appreciated. The thing about philosophy is that one question spawns a large variety of other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phillip Quinn outlines the basic idea of epistemic parity in the following passage:

> The notion of epistemic parity appears attractive from the outset.
>    Every ethics should include fairness, and epistemic parity seems to
>    do no more than introduce considerations of fairness into the ethics
>    of belief. Initially the idea seems simple enough. One should demand
>    no more, and no less, by way of justification for beliefs in one area
>    of inquiry than one does in another. Equally stringent standards of
>    rationality should apply in all cognitive domains. For example, belief
>    in God should not have to satisfy higher standards in order to be
>    rational or justified than does belief in the external world or other
>    minds. (P.L. Quinn, 'Epistemic Parity and Religious Argument', 
>    Philosophical Perspectives, Vol. 5, Philosophy of Religion (1991), p.317.

If this conveys the central idea, one wonders how reasonable it is. Aristotle says in Nicomachean Ethics, I.3, that 'Our discussion will be adequate if it has as much clearness as the subject-matter admits of; for precision is not to be sought for alike in all discussions, any more than in all the products of the crafts' (Barnes, 'The Complete Works of Aristotle', Princeton : Princeton University Press, 1984, 2, p.1730.)

Aristotle clearly recognises that one cannot reasonably expect or require the same rigorous standard of proof from an orator as one can from a mathematician. Equally he himself cannot offer the same degree of rigour in discussing ethical topics as he uses in setting out his logical theory : the subject-matter does not allow it.

Precision and rigour have to be relativised, indexed, to subject-matter. If this is so then the requirement of epistemic parity does not appear reasonable.

But you mainly wanted to know what epistemic parity is. This I hope I have indicated clearly.

As to your rider, if the pluralist endorses epistemic parity in the particular field of religion, and not across the piece, then s/he should apply the same standards of proof or argument to one faith as to another. This need not mean that the two faiths will score equally by the relevant standards, since one may have epistemic merits that that the other lacks : mertis e.g. of consistency, comprehensiveness, clarity, economy of assumptions, &c.

Answer (score 0):

> Would a pluralist say there is epistemic parity between two faiths?

Not necessarily, and in practice almost never https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_pluralism

In my experience, religious people never accept epistemic parity, or why would you remain under the umbrella of that faith? Perennialism, and ecumenism, sure. But I think only atheists and some agnostics go for full epistemic parity, by being non-partisan. Being epistemically non-partisan, is going to result in science